# Stop inheritance for document library or list in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, inheritance

I have created a subsite, where I have kept the inheritance from the parent site.

But what I would like to do is to create several document libraries where I stop the inheritance of the parent/sub site.

It is not an issue to stop the inheritance. But when I open the document library, press Library Setting, Permissions for this document library and then grant permissions to one AD group it gives the same permissions for the entire subsite.

I have tried to follow the instructions on the Microsoft TechNet - although they only have a description for SP2013 which isn't quite the same - can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

BR Line

Problem solved - but thanks for comments. 
I created a new group for the subsite with the proper permissions, then after stopping the inheritance for the library I deleted all the other groups with AD groups in them, and added the AD group I wanted for the new group. Now I just need to test if I have to make a new group for each of my different libraries...

Comment: You will have to 'Edit User Permission' for the AD Group after inheritance is broken if you want unique permission for that particular AD Group in the Document Library

Comment: I have tried that and tried with single users, but it keep adding the group/user to the overall permissions for the subsite even though I only grant it on library/list level. 
Perhaps a specific setting in the Site collection features has been disabled - even though I can't figure out which one.

Comment: As far as I know there is no feature at the SC level especially when you were able to break the inheritance. Check this article if you haven't yet tried this. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?CTT=1&CorrelationId=192edb3b-c817-4e3d-8d5d-8480668ba73f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: That was the article I read. But I think I have cracked the code... I will have to make a new group on the site collection with proper permission and then delete the other groups in the specific library. I'm gonna try it. But thanks.